# Handle hitting partial URL in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, prettyfaces

I'm using JSF 2.0.5, Tomcat 7.0.12 and  prettyfaces.

My web.xml file is:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

My pretty file configuration:

```
<url-mapping>
    <pattern>/</pattern>
    <view-id>/jsp/index.jsf</view-id>
</url-mapping>
```

My index.jsp file is empty.

My question is, when I write in the url 'foo.com' he is eventually redirecting (301) to 
http://www.foo.com/jsp/index.jsf.

Means that in my Phase listener:

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)context.getExternalContext().getRequest(); 
StringBuffer requestUrl = req.getRequestURL(); // i get http://www.foo.com/jsp/index.jsf
```

Can someone explain why he is hitting jsp/index.jsf?

Because i want to recognize when someone hits `foo.com` and `www.foo.com`

Comment: Isn't there an Apache in front of Tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

If someone accesses `http://foo.com/` or `http://www.foo.com/` with your configuration, PrettyFaces intercepts the request and internally forwards it to `/jsp/index.jsf`. You PhaseListener will only see this forwarded request and therefore only sees `/jsp/index.jsf`.

If you want to get the original URL, you could use `PrettyContext.getCurrentInstance().getRequestURL().toURL()`.

However, one thing that is a bit weird in your case is that you write that the users gets redirected (301) when he access the root path. This may cause that my suggestion from above won't work because after a redirect you loose all the information from the original request.

Perhaps you could try to remove the `welcome-file` entry from your `web.xml` and make sure that you don't have any other rewrite rules in your `pretty-config.xml` that may cause this redirect.

Answer (score 0):

The "/" pattern signifies the context root of the application, which in your case would mean www.foo.com. Since you have a mapping from "/" to /jsp/index.jsf, the Servlet container takes you there.

Comment: OK, But I want to recognize when someone hits `foo.com` and `www.foo.com` in the `phase listener` tier... how can i do it?

Comment: Your phase listener will only come into the picture when a request goes through the FacesServlet defined in your web.xml file. If i assume correctly, your url mapping for the FacesServlet must be *.jsf which is not applicable to www.foo.com or foo.com

Comment: if you really want to intercep the request then you can specify n intercepting Filter with the same url mapping as that of jsp/index.jsf